# PagedResultList Instance in Grails 3.1.7 Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-3.0, grails-3.1

Is it possible to create PagedResultList instance or Mock?

For Background: Currently I´m writing Controller Unit tests. If it is necessary I stubbing Service function calls. But some of this functions have `PagedResultList` as return type. So i have to inject a `PagedResultList` instance or `null`.

In some cases I need an instance because the controller do something like this:

```
testFunction(){
    def result = sampleService.doSomething()

    if (result.empty) {
        variable = "it´s empty"
    }
    render variable
}
```

My Test looking like this:

```
void "sample Test"(){
    given:
        controller.sampleService = Mock(SampleService)
        PagedResultList emptyPagedResultList = ?????

    when:
        controller.testFunction()

    then:
        1 * controller.sampleService.doSomething() >> emptyPagedResultList
        response.text == "it´s empty"
}
```

Someone can help me to replace the `?????` with a pice of code to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are a couple options here:

- You could use a real PagedResultList as the `emptyPagedResultList` - See [FooControllerSpec.groovy line 11](https://github.com/ColinHarrington/SO-question-38225537/blob/master/src/test/groovy/testmockexample/FooControllerSpec.groovy#L11) for an example
- You could use another Spock `Mock()` as the `emptyPagedResultList` - See [FooControllerSpec.groovy line 25](https://github.com/ColinHarrington/SO-question-38225537/blob/master/src/test/groovy/testmockexample/FooControllerSpec.groovy#L25) for an example

Comment: Thanks for this great examples.

Comment: @se-jaeger did that answer your question?